# Users of Reactive-native app not showing properly on Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-play, crashlytics

I work with this Reactive-native app that has, more or less, 1500 users on google play but the number of users that appears in Firebase Crashlytics does not exceed 15 or 16. I think something is not correctly linked. The latest version of the app that appears on Firebase seens to be correct.

[In the project settings in integrations is it necessary to link here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sRTT.png)

Image translation:

"Enable integrations that unlock features in firebase, google analytics and google play.

know more

Missing required permissions"

What step might I have done incorrectly to give this effect? I tried to redo the integration step by step as in the documentation, but nothing changed.

Comment: Could you translate the image for us?

Comment: Image translation:
"Enable integrations that unlock features in firebase, google analytics and google play.
know more.
Missing required permissions"